# Where should the sale of a 506(b) real estate syndication be reported on a limited partner's tax return?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

I am a limited partner in a 506(b) real estate syndication, and the property was sold in 2022.

Over the past few years, I have reported passive losses using Form 8582 and Schedule E.

**If the property was sold last year, what are the relevant forms to report the sale on?**

- Schedule D
- Schedule E
- Form 8582
- Somewhere else?

Comment: Did you get a K1 from the partnership?

Comment: Not yet, it's been delayed. I'm trying to figure out where it would go, so I can decide whether to file extension or amendment later.

Comment: I suggest you file an extension and wait for the K1